# Subscription collection only shows most recently added channels their activity

Tags: youtube

I have a subscription collection of 72 channels. The problem I have is that only the channels I added most recently are displayed in the timeline -- older ones their new uploads aren't shown. Whether I sort it on "Uploads Only" or "All Activity" does not make a difference.

Is this a known problem? Is there a fix or should I look into alternatives?

Comment: I found a similar topic in the official Youtube Help Forum, it's a bit old, it doesn't have any reply and it's now closed to new replies.  See [Using the subscription management feature, only displays a few channels per collection](https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/youtube/147u_3XhF1E/discussion).

Comment: I just found another two similar topic in the official Youtube Help Forum, but they are recent. One has several replies including screenshots, but doesn't has a solution (see [My subscription collection isn't showing videos for some particular channels](https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/youtube/e4YTJjBv78c/discussion) ). The other one doesn't have replies yet (see [Youtube "Collections" STILL not updating](https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/youtube/u7ipYd2M544/discussion)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the issue as known problem in the Youtube Help Center nor in the Youtube Help Forum, just few threads but without any conclusive declaration, solution nor recommendations.

As a workaround consider to split your collection in smaller sets. Start creating one with around half of the size of the collection with the problem, i.e. 30. If the problems persists, repeat until you find the collection size that works properly.

Also consider to report the issue to Youtube.

**References from the YouTube Help Center**
[Known issues](https://support.google.com/youtube/known-issues/16903?hl=en)
[Report a YouTube issue](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4347644)

Comment: Seems like this is the problem at hand indeed. I'll submit a bugreport in the coming days but I don't have much hope for a fix considering the lack of (useful) response to the existing topics. Thanks for looking!